# C++ standard library use in malware

Tags: malware, source-code, c++

I was recently analyzing the sources of ZeuS, ZeroAccess, Carberp and other professional malware and there was one thing which I found weird:

The authors did not use the standard library `std::`-functions very frequently when they could have. I mean stuff like `std::fstream` / `std::string` / `std::cout` (for debugging).

My question is why? A lot of tasks could be accomplished easier if they would use these functions. I don't think efficiency was their concern since the speed boost wouldn't be worth the time spend.

[Source example here](https://github.com/Visgean/Zeus/tree/translation/source/client)

Comment: Were they using C equivalents to these, or trying to avoid strings and stream handling, or what? Input/Output is a heavily language-dependent thing, so maybe they were just more comfortable with C.

Comment: https://github.com/Visgean/Zeus/tree/translation/source/client , I suggest you have a look at the sources because I don't really know how to describe that. They stick to C style and WINAPI functions but I don't understand why.

Comment: rephrased the question because it was a little hard to decypher

Comment: Using c++ just adds overhead to the malware and results in bloated malware.  Also there is no guarantee C++ libraries are available on a PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a malware, you should make as few assumptions as possible on the libraries existing on the target (victim) machine. As the sources you show in comment are for Windows, all you can safely assume is that the functions for WINAPI calls will be available, because any additional dependency on redistributable bits for any C or C++ system may be present or not: many Window machines have no installed development tools, and they only have the libraries (DLL) that were required by other software.

That means that to be able to use functions from the C++ (or even C) library, the developper should statically link the used standard library resulting in a heavy application, when a malware should be tiny in order not to sched light on it because of its size.

That's a possible reason why the developpers of Zeus make an intensive usage of WINAPI calls and avoid calls to the C standard library, not speaking of the C++ one which would add a new layer and some overhead in size.

Comment: I thought that the standart library is pretty much ALWAYS included. Wikipedia seems to back me up : "In the C++ programming language, the C++ Standard Library is a collection of classes and functions, which are written in the core language and part of the C++ ISO Standard itself."

Comment: @PePePlusPlus: If a C (resp. C++) developpement environment is installed, then the standard requires the C (resp C++) library to be also installed. But many Windows box contain no C++ dev. environment, so the libraries may not be present.

Comment: The std library can be used on any program and it will run without requiring any pre-installing any library, software or DLL

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: Of course if it is statically linked...

Answer (score 0):

Also I might think of it being a way to obfuscate code in order to by pass detection.

If an antivirus has the use of standard libraries used in such a way as a trigger for malicious code then they may just not use those libraries and go about a different weird way of doing things on purpose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It is due to the needs to run the process silently. What happen when you try to run an executable with missing dll ? an error messages or an install shield will be trigger. The coder do not want this because the main objective is to run on more machines as possible. By using "std" library the coder avoid some dependencies issues and he will be sure that the software will run on every machine.

Comment: But the OP says "_use the standard library std::-functions as **infrequently** as possible_". More likely they were a C programmer at heart but happened to need to write it in C++ for some reason.

Comment: oups my bads lolz sry ... I have missed a good moment to shut my mouth up lol  cheers :)

Comment: you can delete this if you misread the question ...